# Unable to instantiate java.lang.classnotfoundexception android

Tags: android, classnotfound

I know there are a number of these already but it seems that none of them address my issue.  What is weird is that this error ONLY occurs on a signed package (running it from Eclipse works perfectly) and this only popped up with my most recent update that I published (but I can't think of anything relevant that I changed...)

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.domain.app.MainApp
```

I have use a class that extends Application in order to use a library.  The applicable manifest portion looks like this:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/launcher" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme" android:name=".MainApp">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
               <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Anyone know what could be causing it?

Comment: Proguard might do such issues.

Comment: I don't have the proguard file...deleted it a while back.

Comment: and what package is your `MainApp` that extends `Application` in?

Comment: same package as the classes   com.domain.app   Again, this works fine from eclipse...the app runs normal.  The only issues is when I try to install the signed package.

Comment: did you manage to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what was wrong but after cleaning, re-exporting, and re-uploading the problem stopped occurring.